# Jquery sliders do not work in aspx page but works fine in HTML

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

Scenario: 
Within an asp.net site, we have 3 jquery sliders on ASPX page.

The three sliders (can be seen in the below jsfiddle link) are
a) Price
b) Variant
c) Related items (it is within the tab)

The JSfiddle link is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/DfKwy/5/

The 3rd slider (related-items sliders) is creating problem such as the previous & next arrow buttons do not slide and also when this slider is present, the other sliders do not slide (user doesn't get to see previous / next buttons).

I just took html/script/css from the aspx page and put them in jsfiddle & everything seems to be working. However on the live asp.net it doesn't work. I have made the asp.net as public facing and I can share the url also.

The aspx page uses updatePanel, ajax. Even in my jsfiddle example I have commented some script blocks.

Please help in debugging this further.

PS: For some reason, I can't submit this question without posting code. Please check the above jsfiddle link for complete code. The below code is just couple of lines only and is not complete.

```
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are other scripts/line of codes affecting your desired outcome? Maybe your'e referencing conflicting jquery versions such?

Please see link.

[conflict between jquery-1.2.6.min.js and jquery-1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243677/conflict-between-jquery-1-2-6-min-js-and-jquery-1-4-2)

Comment: :Thanks for reply. I don't know the conflicting ones. But if you open the jsFiddle link and check 'manage resources', are there any conflicting ones? Let me know